# Как собрать библиотеки WebM для MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, кросс-компиляция, компиляция

**Стоит задача реализовать в приложении на C++ потоковое видео** (для браузеров), дали направление - WebM. На [официальном сайте](http://www.webmproject.org/code/) куча репозиториев (кодеки, парсеры, tools всякие...), а [тут](https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/udpsample) только инструкции для VisualStudio.

**Вопрос: какие из перечисленных на сайте WebM репозитории нужны для поставленной задачи?**
Подскажите пожалуйста план действий.

*PS: Нужны библиотеки для MinGW (lib*.a) для статической линковки*

Comment: Попробуйте [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)  очень хорошо собирается с MinGW.

Comment: А реализовать на ней поток для воспроизведения в HTML5 получится?

Comment: А что вы сделать-то хотите? Вы хотите стримить видео откуда-то и смотреть через браузер?

Comment: Да, я же написал - потоковое видео (c веб-камеры) из приложения на C++ в браузер. Сейчас всё работает покадрово: сделал снимок - отправил на сервер, и так 25 раз в секунду. Но людям нужен "стрим"...

Comment: @Iceman, то, что вы написали можно трактовать по-разному. Поэтому я и уточнил.

Comment: @Iceman можно открыть браузер и смотреть видео с веб камеры. Если нужно считывать видео поток с камеры то какой видеокодек и какой протокол идет с камеры ?

Comment: Можно, но во-первых, браузеры спрашивают доступ к камере, а этого не надо, во-вторых, Chrome не поддерживает getUserMedia по не https соединению. Поэтому я спрашиваю про поток из приложения на C++

Comment: @Iceman Библиотека ffmpeg позволяет работать с различнами видеокодоками(H.264) и протоколами(RTSP).